# I/O Failure when overwriting entire disk

Tags: hard-disk, dd

I'm trying to write random data over a partition on my local hard disk. I'm booted into a recovery live CD (Clonezilla) and have tried the following:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1024 count=4 | base64 | \
    sudo cryptsetup plainOpen --key-file - /dev/sda5 rando
$ dd if=/dev/zero | pv -ptra | sudo dd of=/dev/mapper/rando
```

In laymans terms:

1. Open `/dev/sda5` as a plain encrypted disk with a random passphrase. (ie: initialize an AES cipher with a random key)
2. Fill the virtual disk with zeroes, meaning that the underlying media is filled with random data, effectively filling the disk with random data for reasons™.

This fails at around 250GiB, and the partition is around 512GiB in size.

I've also tried the good old:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda5 bs=4096
```

and it also fails at about 250GiB. I've tried resuming the overwriting later on with `seek`, but it also fails again.

I'm thinking this is a disk issue, but I have no way of validating this. Is there a tool that will confirm my suspicions and figure out which sectors are failing?

Comment: Why not simply `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda5`? What is the error message? What is in the kernel log (`dmesg | tail -n 20`)?

Comment: @HaukeLaging The first way I did it results in a faster write that isn't as CPU-bound. Running things through a defined AES cipher is much faster than `/dev/urandom`. Both fail. `blk-update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector N` and other bad things come out of `dmesg`.

Comment: Can you paste your error output? Also you might want to try to run `fsck` to check your filesystem.

Comment: There is no filesystem, I'm writing to an empty partition. There are disk I/O errors. At this point I just want to zero everything out that I possibly can.

Answer (score 0):

If the disk is not completely failing and there are just a few damaged sectors then you can try to repair them with

```
hdparm --write-sector
```

using the sector numbers from `dmesg`. You may also use `smartctl` to have a look at the drive's self-test data or start self-tests.

Comment: Okay, so if this disk is toast, is there a way to zero out the disk, skipping bad sectors and completing no matter what?

Comment: You can make `dd` ignore read errors; I am not aware of a way to make it ignore write errors. But every time dd aborts you can get the next defective sector from `dmesg` and skip this sector.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay - You can zero out the disk using `hdparm`'s secure erase facility.  Make sure it's connected to your SATA/SCSI/IDE cable and not USB though as the latter can cause issues.  Note that this will zero the whole disk - not just a partition.